# Propane tankless heater before an electric one?

Tags: tankless

I am renovating a property that I use for a bed and breakfast. I have a fairly well working 30 gallon water heater that is electric. I also have a propane tank that I use for limited heating in my shop when I need it. I also have a nice tankless propane water heater. I am thinking about installing the tankless to pre-heat the water to the electric unit to save some money. Propane is cheap and easy here. Electric is relatively expensive.

What do you think?

Comment: About what? Please revise to be more specific, and take the [tour] when you get a moment. We aren't a discussion forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tankless water heater before the reg hot water](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116066/tankless-water-heater-before-the-reg-hot-water)

Comment: Can you give us what one therm of propane and one kWh of electricity costs for you?

Comment: Why mess with the electric at all? If you've got a tankless propane water heater, just use that.